# Why is my CKEditor Var not being seen by function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, ckeditor

I have the following in my document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(event){

var editor1 = CKEDITOR.replace("noteDetail", {
    baseHref: CKEDITOR.basePath,
    customConfig: CTX_PATH + '/resources/js/ckeditor_config.js',
    removeButtons: 'Save'
});
```

I have a saveNote() function which I try to capture the text from my CKeditor instance into a var called detail  but it does not see editor1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 var detail = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

the IDE tells me that it is unresolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use `CKEDITOR.instances.noteDetail` or simply `editor1` if that call  `var detail = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` is being made within `ready` function scope.